# Postgres generated columns produces a syntax error

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver, generated-columns

I want to create column with [Generated Columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html)

Postgres version: `PostgreSQL 15.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit`

Dbeaver version: `23.0.1.202303250535`

query (yes, i now it violates 1NF):

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees (
  first_name VARCHAR(50),
  last_name VARCHAR(50),
  full_name VARCHAR(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (first_name || ' ' || last_name) STORED
);
```

output:

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "("

I did a little searching and end up in [this](https://github.com/kyleconroy/sqlc/issues/669) GitHub issue which has a linked pull request to support generated columns. Does dbeaver not support [Generated Columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html) or what?

I'm trying to use `pgAdmin 4 version 6.15` then execute the above query and run it successfully. How can I execute that query successfully on Dbeaver?

Comment: Sounds very much like a dbeaver bug, yes.

Comment: Just use [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) and make your life easier.

Comment: Ran it in latest DBeaver Version  23.0.2, worked just fine. What version did you use. And as Adrian says you can always use psql.

Comment: @Belayer my dbeaver version si 23.0.1. when i'm create this question, 23.0.1 is the latest version, after update to 23.0.2 the query run successfully, thx.